# Is there a way to know what a process is doing on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, process, tasks

Windows 10 has a lot of strangely named process running and we don't know exactly what they're doing.

For example, the "Runtime Broker.exe" task is described as a process that helps to manage permissions. How to know what each "Runtime Broker.exe" is doing, which registry it is accessing or which application it is related to?

Comment: There is a tool you can use called the [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) that can tell you exactly what a process is doing. I doubt you are prepared to interpret all of the information you will find.  If you are smart enough, you can use the built in filter editor to narrow down the information being displayed.  Good luck! :)

Comment: Also, there is no "one place" to answer your question.  You can single out the Microsoft processes and focus on the remainder.  So look at the exe name and location, look at the signature.. dig into the processes that are suspect.  This is not unlike trying to protect your home from intruders.  You can't investigate everyone.. you need to figure out how to identify potential problems.

Comment: RunTimeBroker is the program that says "*<app> trying to access camera - do you allow it"* for Window Store Apps. In Task Manager's Details' tab right click column header and select *Add Columns*. Select *Package Name* to match to which exe. It's ShellExperience, Search, LockScreen, etc.

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas. It's something like that I'm searching for. I'll vote up when you put like an answer.

Comment: @user1292580 good tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool you can use called the [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)  that can tell you exactly what a process is doing.

doubt you are prepared to interpret all of the information you will find so if you are smart enough ;) .. you can use the built in filter editor to narrow down the information being displayed.

Also, there is no "one place" to answer your question. You can single out the Microsoft processes and focus on the remainder. So look at the exe name and location, look at the signature.. dig into the processes that are suspect. This is not unlike trying to protect your home from intruders. You can't investigate everyone.. you need to figure out how to identify potential problems.